# Consequences of changing organization name

Tags: organization

I wanted to ask whether there can be any consequences after changing the **organization name** in **Company Information** settings.
I've already searched for that in Salesforce Help but there's nothing mentioned about considerations nor consequences: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338722&type=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there are any consequences in standard functionality. I've changed organization names for multiple customers without negative effects.

There is a possibility that there is custom logic in your org that uses the organization name. But even then the chances are small that a change in organization name will actually break anything (it is typically used for display purposes only).